# How can I edit an api url using a TextField?

Tags: list, api, flutter, dart, textfield

I am trying to make my api url be able to be modified so that I can add and remove stocks from my ListView.builder.

Here is my http request:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'api_data.dart';

String stockWatchlist = 't,aapl,tsla,amd';
String sandToken = 'Tsk_38ddda0b877a4510b42a37ae713cdc96';

Future<List<Stock>> fetchStocks(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client.get(
      'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=$stockWatchlist&types=stats,quote&token=$sandToken');
  return compute(parseStocks, response.body);
}

List<Stock> parseStocks(String responseBody) {
  dynamic data = json.decode(responseBody);

  List<Stock> stockList = [];
  data.forEach((key, value) => stockList.add(Stock(key, value)));

  return stockList;
}

class Stock {
  String symbol;
  dynamic data;

  Stock(this.symbol, this.data);
}
```

Here is my TextField:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return TextField(
      onSubmitted: (newText) {
      },
      controller: myController,
      cursorColor: Colors.white,
      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: 'Add Stock',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        suffixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: kMediumText,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
    );
  }
}
```

The goal is to be able to change the value of

```
String stockWatchlist = 't,aapl,tsla,amd';
```

with the TextField but I am unsure of how to edit a string with a TextField.  As this is my first app I have ever made my knowledge is very limited.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a `List<String>` like so: `List<String> stocks = ['tsla', 'aapl', 'amd']`.

In the `onSubmitted` callback, you should add the string to a list. `stocks.add(text);`

To convert this to the comma separated String, just use the `join` method:
`stocks.join(',');` which will produce `"tsla,aapl,amd"`

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me figure out this question.  However I still do not know how to tie this in with my listview so I can also delete from the list.  I will mess around with it and maybe ask in a different thread.